# Error Saving geodjango PointField

Tags: django, postgresql, postgis, psycopg2, geodjango

I have a geo model with a PointField property. Everything works perfectly locally, but when I try to save an instance on the server, I get the following error:

```
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x00
```

I dug into the source and found that the values are being serialized differently; specifically, that value isn't being escaped before the query is executed on the server. It looks like the escaping is being done by `psycopg2.Binary.getquoted()` and sure enough, it doesn't return the correct value on the server.

On my machine:

```
from psycopg2 import Binary
Binary('\0').getquoted() # > "'\\\\000'::bytea"
```

On the server:

```
from psycopg2 import Binary
Binary('\0').getquoted() # > "'\\000'::bytea"
```

Okay, that explains why it thinks I'm trying to insert a null byte. (Because I am.)  So now I know enough about what's going wrong to find a similar report by Jonathan S. on the [django-users group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-users/RxTmn3HVPDE) but, like Jonathan, I don't know if this is a bug or configuration error.

Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Here's some info about the setups:

```
          My computer      Server
OS        OSX 10.7         CentOS 5.5
Python    2.7              2.6
Django    1.3              1.3
Postgres  9.0.4            9.9.1
postgis   1.5.2            1.5.3-2.rhel5
geos      3.3.0            3.3.0-1.rhel5
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Finally managed to figure it out.

The difference, as documented in [this ticket](http://psycopg.lighthouseapp.com/projects/62710/tickets/69-pqescapebyteaconn-does-not-escape-backslashes-on-postgres-91-server#ticket-69-10), is that Postgres 9.1 has `standard_conforming_strings` on by default. Which wouldn't be a problem, really, except Django's adapter has a bug that basically ignores it. [A patch was submitted](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16778) and it's working for me.

For those unwilling or unable to apply the patch or upgrade, you can just use [this database adapter instead](https://github.com/matthewwithanm/django-scspostgis).

Comment: Thanks for sharing matthew. I'm really glad that I stumbled upon your post :)

Comment: Thanks! setting standard_conforming_strings = off in postgresql.conf also worked for me.