# Django error when converting OFTInteger to Decimal

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, postgresql-9.1, geos

I'm building a database with geo data in it using : PostgreSQL 9.1, Django 1.3.1, psycopg2 2.4.5 and using libraries GEOS 3.3.0, PostGIS 1.5.4 and ProJ 4.7.0.

I have a command to load the shape files into the database with a bit of optimization to have the shape more simple.

To keep the model simple, i will just put the problematic fields:

```
class Circonscription(models.Model):
    shape = models.GeometryField()
    simple_shape = models.GeometryField()
    centroid = models.PointField(null=True)
```

When i want to create one from the shape file, i do this:

```
Circonscription.objects.create(
            id_cep=feature['id_cep'],
            co_cep=feature['co_cep'],
            nm_cep=feature['nm_cep'],
            nmtri_cep=feature['nmtri_cep'],
            dh_maj=feature['dh_maj'],
            shape=geometry.wkt,
            simple_shape=simple_geometry.wkt,
            centroid=geometry.geos.centroid)
```

Now when i run my command, it fails with this error:

```
File "/home/pg/Projets/python/myproject/circonscriptions/management/commands/loadshapefiles.py", line 174, in add_boundaries_for_layer
centroid=geometry.geos.centroid)
File "/home/pg/.virtualenvs/myproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 138, in create
    return self.get_query_set().create(**kwargs)
  File "/home/pg/.virtualenvs/myproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 360, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "/home/pg/.virtualenvs/myproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 460, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert, force_update=force_update)
  File "/home/pg/.virtualenvs/myproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 543, in save_base
    for f in meta.local_fields if not isinstance(f, AutoField)]
  File "/home/pg/.virtualenvs/myproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/subclassing.py", line 28, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pg/.virtualenvs/myproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 786, in get_db_prep_save
    return connection.ops.value_to_db_decimal(self.to_python(value),
  File "/home/pg/.virtualenvs/myproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 761, in to_python
    return decimal.Decimal(value)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/decimal.py", line 658, in __new__
    raise TypeError("Cannot convert %r to Decimal" % value)
TypeError: Cannot convert <django.contrib.gis.gdal.field.OFTInteger object at 0x2458b50> to Decimal
```

Does anybody have a clue about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It somehow had to do with the encoding of the values and then another error was about [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7682460/1524663) which finally solved it. 
Be sure to convert the values to the correct encoding (utf-8) before passing them to the model to save.

Answer (score 0):

Decimal expects a String, but you are feeding it an OTFInteger, you need to convert it to string somewhere in the process